# Solution for acting as an identity provider?

Tags: authentication, idp

My company (call it ExampleCompany) would like other applications to be able to “Sign on with ExampleCompany,” in the same way that you can Sign On with Google, LinkedIn, GitHub, etc. Any recommendations for going about this? Would prefer to take advantage of existing infrastructure and solutions. Thanks so much for your guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Firebase as an alternative? Firebase has many sign on options, check this [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth).  I used it for a test web app and I used phone sign on authentication, here is a lab [lab](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web#0) that might help you.